# Initialize NSDate with custom date

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for something like:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithYear:1984 month:10 Day:8];
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote a category for this task. NSDate is missing a lot of useful methods.

```
@interface NSDate (missingFunctions) 
+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day;
@end


@implementation NSDate (missingFunctions)

+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [components setYear:year];
    [components setMonth:month];
    [components setDay:day];
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}   
@end
```

Comment: It isn't missing. It's intentionally not there. The theory is that a hypothetical `+[NSDate dateWithYear:month:day:]` would make developers presuppose that everybody used the Gregorian calendar. Better, in Apple's mind, to split apart moment-in-time manipulation (`NSDate`) from real-world calendar manipulation (`NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`.)

Comment: You should read the date programming guide for the rationale of why those functions are missing.  Basically an NSDate just a particular point in time.  Things like years, months and days within a month are meaningless except in the context of a particular calendar. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i

Comment: This code will return incorrect results if current system calendar is non-Gregorian. Please change calendar initialization to `[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease]`.

Comment: And you should be explicit and specify whether the date is relative to where the user is currently located (`[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]`) or absolute (`[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]`).

Comment: All of that rationale is negated by a `year:month:day:calendarIdentifier:` method. No excuses for not having a convenience method here in my opinion. Too much boilerplate for your standard "give me a specific date" need.