# How do I compare dates to implement signs of the zodiac in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsdate

How to implement this issue: 
When set person birthday date to appear sign of the zodiac?
Please help to solve my issue.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[_birtDateTextField setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[_datePicker date]]];
```

Comment: no, I think Astakhoff just doesn't know how to compare and/or initialize NSDates. The same question could have been asked about, say, putting a icon up on a person's birthday relative to Ground Hog day or something just as stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the NSDate, not just the formatted date. Now you'll want to compare the date the person entered against the zodiacal dates.

This question, [How to compare two NSDates: Which is more recent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent), show you how to compare dates. A little bit of cut/paste code from that question is:

```
    if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2"); 
    }
```

Now you just need to create an NSDate for each sign of the zodiac. I don't know those dates so just google for them. Again, the search function is your friend here. Look at [Initialize NSDate with custom date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861182/initialize-nsdate-with-custom-date) and notice this line:

```
    [calendar dateFromComponents:components]
```

Be sure to set the years correctly!